# Can't get Set-Cookie header in production

Tags: cookies, next.js, nestjs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront

My stack is the following: **NestJS backend** (Express under the hood) deployed on **Elastic Beanstalk**, **NextJS frontend** deployed on **AWS Amplify**, CloudFront as CDN, and I can't get `Set-Cookie` header back to the frontend NextJS app, nor a cookie is being set.
FE and BE are on a different domains.

Locally everything works fine, when FE and BE apps are local, eg. I'm getting `Set-Cookie` and a cookie is stored in the browser. When FE is local and BE is deployed, it doesn't work as expected also when communicating between the two. CORS is being set up and there's no error there. Cookie options seems right too.

On the backend, **CORS** has been set with 3 options, out of the factory method, eg. `app.enableCors({...})`:

- explicit origin (no wildcard) - works with allowed credentials turned on
- `credentials` set to `true` - allow credentials header
- allowed headers
  So, CORS is working, **no error there**, just not returning `Set-Cookie` header when deployed.

For **cookie**, I'm using `cookie-parser` npm module, and having set up the following options for the cookie when returning the response for `POST /auth/login` request:

- `httpOnly: true` - no script reading
- `maxAge` (1 day into the future from request time)
- `sameSite: 'none'` - cross-site enabled
- `secure: true` - https (required for cross-site)

On the frontend, I'm using NextJS with `axios` npm module to fetch an API. Also, I'm having `credentials` set to `true`.

I tried to update CORS settings on load balancers, eg. proxy for the backend, and was doing a lot of research on Stack Overflow and other platforms, but couldn't find a solution. Most solutions mention that some options are missing for the backend, like CORS and a cookie settings, and `credentials: true` for the frontend. But as mentioned before, seems I got that covered. CloudFront settings didn't help either. CloudFront caching policy - didn't help. Something is missing or am doing it wrong.

Everything points that the AWS has to be set up properly(default/basic settings), but I don't know what excatly. Any help?

Comment: It's hard for me to get a full picture of exactly how you have things deployed, but based on this `FE and BE are on different domains` -- you can't set cookies with responses from a different domain. Requests to your backend can only set cookies for your backend domain. Maybe that's your issue.

Comment: @sytech I figured it out. The backend was missing a valid SSL certificate. FE and BE couldn't communicate if either was on HTTP. Both have to be on HTTPS for HTTP-only and cross-origin cookies, not just FE, which makes sense.